# Программа по плавному скрытию текста при помощи jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

В чем ошибка программы? Я неправильно подключил jQuery? Или ошибка в самом коде?

Вот код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div><p id = "hide">Этот текст медленно исчезнет по нажатию кнопки снизу</p><div>


  <button type = "button" onclick = "document.getElementById('hide').fadeOut(500)">Click Me!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementById(...).fadeOut is not a function"

`fadeOut()` - это не функция стандартного `js`, а функция `jQuery`.

Перепишите код используя селекторы `jQuery`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div><p id = "hide">Этот текст медленно исчезнет по нажатию кнопки снизу</p><div>


  <button type = "button" onclick = "$('#hide').fadeOut(500)">Click Me!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div><p id = "hide">Этот текст медленно исчезнет по нажатию кнопки снизу</p><div>


  <button type = "button" onclick = "$('#hide').fadeOut(500);">Click Me!</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не успел )))!!!